# Can't match css file with segment uri Spring Framewwork 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Hei guys! I have a servlet config as below.

### vietjob-servlet

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="vjb.de.vietjob" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>



<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:lang" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And in web xml i declare the uri for servlet

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>vietjob</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vietjob</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

If i write all controller request mapping under /, everything is ok, servlet can load all libraries inside resources folder. But when i give controller a segment, i got error with

```
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
```

For details the link *localhost:8001/vjb.de/ehdokas.do* is working but *localhost:8001/vjb.de/employee/ehdokas.do* not work. I guess that when i give a segment, the servlet will scan employee/resources instead /resources, so the error occurred.

And another issue: when user login into system, the link was changed from http://localhost:8001/vjb.de/ehdokas.do to http://localhost:8001/vjb.de/employee/ehdokas.do. How can i config a same controller with all urls, i mean controller can run without relative to url address. Every link abc/def/ehdokas.do or abc/ehdokas.do also call to controller ehdokas.do?!

### Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EhdokasController {

    @Inject
    private EhdokasDao ehdokasdao;
    @Inject
    private AlaDao aladao;


    public AlaDao getAlaDao(){
        return aladao;
    }
    public void setAlaDao(AlaDao aladao){
        this.aladao=aladao;
    }

    public EhdokasDao getEhdokasDao() {
        return ehdokasdao;
    }

    public void setEhdokasDao(EhdokasDao ehdokasdao) {
        this.ehdokasdao = ehdokasdao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEmployeePage(@RequestParam(value="tunnus") String tunnus, Model model){
        System.out.println("ehdokasdao: "+ehdokasdao);
        EhdokasImpl ehdokas = (EhdokasImpl) ehdokasdao.getEhdokasByTunnus(tunnus);
        model.addAttribute("ehdokas", ehdokas);
        return "ehdokas/ehdokas_home";
    }

    // Siirtää ehdokas lomake sivulle
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lomake.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forwardToLomake(Model model) {
        Ehdokas ehdokas = new EhdokasImpl();
        List<Integer> listId = aladao.getListAlaId();
        model.addAttribute("listId", listId);
        model.addAttribute("ehdokas", ehdokas);
        return "lomake/lomake_ehdokas";
    }

    // ota syötetyt tiedot lomakkeesta
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lomake.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getTietoLomake(
            @ModelAttribute(value = "ehdokas") @Valid EhdokasImpl ehdokas, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "lomake/lomake_ehdokas";
        } else {
            ehdokasdao.postEhdokas(ehdokas);
            return "redirect:/ehdokas.do";
        }
    }

    // näytä kaikki ehdokkaat tietokannasta
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ehdokas.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEhdokkaat(Model model) {
        List<String> kaupunkiList = ehdokasdao.getKotiKaupunki();
        List<Ehdokas> ehdokkaat = ehdokasdao.showEhdokas();
        model.addAttribute("ehdokkaat", ehdokkaat);
        model.addAttribute("kaupunkiList", kaupunkiList);
        model.addAttribute("ehdokas", new EhdokasImpl());
        return "ehdokas/ehdokas_list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ehdokas.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showEhdokkaat(
            @ModelAttribute(value = "ehdokas") EhdokasImpl ehdokas,@PathVariable(value="kaupunki") String kaupunki, @PathVariable(value="id") int id,@RequestParam(value="submit") String submit, Model model) {
        System.out.println(submit);
        if(submit.equals("Hae") || submit.equals("Search")){
            List<String> kaupunkiList = ehdokasdao.getKotiKaupunki();
            List<Ehdokas> ehdokkaat = ehdokasdao.getEhdokasByKaupunki(kaupunki);
            model.addAttribute("ehdokkaat", ehdokkaat);
            model.addAttribute("kaupunkiList", kaupunkiList);
              return "ehdokas/ehdokas_list";
        } else if (submit.equals("More") || submit.equals("Lisätieto")){

              model.addAttribute("id",id);
              return "redirect:yksiehdokas.do";
        } else 
            return "redirect:ehdokas.do";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/yksiehdokas.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showYksiEhdokas(@RequestParam(value="id") int id, Model model ){
        Ehdokas ehdokas = ehdokasdao.searchEhdokasById(id);
        model.addAttribute("ehdokas", ehdokas);
        return "ehdokas/ehdokas_yksi";
    }

    /*siirrä apply sivulle*/
    @RequestMapping(value="/apply.do", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forwardToApply(Model model){
        Kayttaja kayttaja = new KayttajaImpl();
        Ehdokas ehdokas = new EhdokasImpl();

        model.addAttribute("kayttaja", kayttaja);
        model.addAttribute("ehdokas", ehdokas);
        return "apply";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/apply.do", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getInfoEmployee(@ModelAttribute(value="ehdokas") EhdokasImpl ehdokas){
        ehdokasdao.postEhdokas(ehdokas);
        return "redirect:ehdokas.do";
    }


    @ModelAttribute("kieliList")
    public List<String> getKieli() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("English");
        list.add("Finnish");
        list.add("Germany");
        return list;

    }

    @ModelAttribute("tutkinnot")
    public List<String> getTutkinto() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Päiväkoti");
        list.add("Peruskoulu");
        list.add("Lukio");
        list.add("AMK");
        list.add("Yliopisto");
        return list;
    }

}
```

### Jsp file

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/navbar-bootstrap.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/logo-banner.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/menu-bootstrap.jsp"%>
<script src="<c:url value="resources/bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
<link href="resources/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
 /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    .container-fluid {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .form-control{
         width: 30px;
    }
</style>
<title><spring:message code="employee.page.list" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
      <form:form class="form-inline" action="ehdokas.do" modelAttribute="ehdokas" method="POST">
        <form:select class="form-control" path="kaupunki">
        <form:option value="">select city</form:option>
            <form:options items="${kaupunkiList}"></form:options>
        </form:select>
        <spring:message code="button.search" var="search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="${search }" />
       </form:form>
      <h3><spring:message code="kaikki.ehdokas"></spring:message></h3>
      <hr>
      <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="ehdokas" items="${ehdokkaat}">
      <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${ehdokas.suku} "></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ehdokas.etu} "></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ehdokas.sukupuoli} "></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ehdokas.kaupunki} "></c:out></td>

        <form:form action="ehdokas.do" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${ehdokas.id }" />
        <spring:message code="button.more" var="more"/>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="${more }" /></td>
        </form:form>
      </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/footer-bootstrap.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your controller and jsp file ?

Comment: You're using relative paths. Don't. Use absolute ones: `href="<c:url value="/resources/...`

Comment: Still doesn't work bro.

Comment: I'll fixed this. I add two points front of css link and the problem has been resolved. I was on right way when focus to the URL recource folder that servlet will scan. Anyway thanks again for your suggest JB Nizet!

But the twice problem still not fix, someone has ideas?